# MySQL Application Connection

Tags: c#, mysql

If i leave my mysql code like this

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; user id = root; password=pass; database=name");
```

Would other be able to use the application with the mysql database since its using localhost as server ip?

Comment: This will obviously only work if it is executed on the same machine where the DB is located!

Comment: How can i fix that? Or make it so any computer can run it.

Comment: If the db server has a fixed IP you use enter this or, much better, use a DynDNS service and use this domain name!

Comment: Ok thanks will use this info!

Comment: It would be better not to provide root access thru the app.